# How to thoroughly rename a Universal Framework in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos, tvos

I'm building a Framework, originally named **Iris**.

When trying to publish it as a Cocoapod I found out that **there is an "Iris" framework already**.

And while they have completely diferent purposes and authors, I cannot publish it as a pod with this name. So **I did the unthinkable**!

I tried renaming the whole thing to **IrisKit**.

My Xcode project, now named IrisKit, has 6 targets:

3 Framework targets

```
- IrisKit iOS
- IrisKit tvOS
- IrisKit macOS
```

3 Example Projects

```
- IrisKit Example iOS
- IrisKit Example tvOS
- IrisKit Example macOS
```

Unfortunatly, my Example projects **won't let me import IrisKit** with an error that states:

```
warning: file 'FeedTableViewController.swift' is part of module 'IrisKit'; ignoring import
```

What's a developer to do?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Backup your project, or if you're under source control, create a new branch and work from there.

Here are the steps taken:

**1. Renamed the Project in the project's "Identity and Type"**

[image]

**2. Renamed Schemes to IrisKit**

[image]

**3. Renamed Folders and Groups to IrisKit**

[image]

**4. Updated the info.plist references under Build-Settings > Packaging**

[image]

**5. Updated the Bundle Identifiers under Build-Settings > Packaging**

[image]

**6. Updated the Public Header to IrisKit.h**

[image]

**7. Updated Example projects import to IrisKit**

[image]

**8. Updated Dependency Management:**

```
   - Swift Package Manager
   - Cocoapods specs
```

**9. Finally, and good lord this is important**:

Targets that are not meant to be built with the framework, must have a different product name than the Framework they use. e.g. An Example Project that showcases the framework

It may sound obvious, but can be easy to miss when mass renaming things

-

**The framework with the same name for multiple build targets:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And the Example target. Notice that the name is different from the framework targets.**

[image]

Took me a while to figure this one out. Hope it helps.

Comment: huge kudos for explanation :)